# Extracting NSString from NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to extract an NSString from the NSKeyedArchiver as follows:

```c
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *coder = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[coder encodeInt:1 forKey:@"myField"];
[coder finishEncoding];

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

The problem is that myString is nil (NSLog prints '(null)'). What is wrong with the above code?

Other posts I've read mention that this is usually due to the encoding being wrong (i.e. the NSMutableData is using a different encoding than UTF-8). I've tried all the different types of encoding though, still no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't see where you are encoding a string. Normally you would encode an `NSString` with the `NSKeyedArchiver` and then unarchive it using an `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. It doesn't look like you understand how this all works. I recommend reading about [archiving using Obj-C](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php).

Comment: Thank you, I looked at that link and it explains how to output the encoded data to a file using NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:. However, I'd like to get a string representation of the object into an NSString instead. According to the documentation the NSString initWithData:encoding: method should do the trick (i.e. take NSData and create an NSString from it).

Comment: Just to check that I understand it correctly: I am encoding an int against a key "myField" using the NSKeyedArchiver. The NSKeyedArchiver outputs the encoded data to the NSMutableData 'data'. I then use the 'data' variable to initialize an NSString. The encoding needs to be specified so that the runtime knows how to convert the data into a string (i.e. using the specified string encoding which could be UTF-8, ASCII or a myriad others). Does this sound right?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to convert an object into a JSON string representation and send it to a RESTful web service. I know this KeyedArchiver doesn't convert to JSON, but I thought I'd try and understand this one first.

Comment: If that's the case, you should probably just skip this altogether. Working with JSON is very easy using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). All you need to do is create `NSMutableDictionaries` and then you can convert that to a JSON string.

Comment: I'll give that a go. I was hoping to avoid using a third party library thinking that since iOS is meant for mobile devices (which often use web services) this would be built-in functionality that is easy to use. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No problem. I like using built in solutions as well when possible, but unfortunately Apple doesn't provide JSON support currently. Hopefully they will give us a nice JSON solution in the near future, but with good third party libraries, it's not a huge deal if they decide not to.